# Apache server not working on public ip address

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I installed apache2 on ubuntu 16.04. After installing apache when i tried to open apache2 default page using my ip address it is asking for password. I attached screen shot below. I followed this tutorial.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. There was a problem in my aws instanace security group. HTTP port was not opened there. I edited it and finally i can see apache2 default page.